# Como fazer uma lista horizontal de imagens que não quebre?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Quero fazer uma lista de imagens na horizontal, mas estão caindo, olhem:

[image: Lista de imagens "quebrando"]

Meu CSS:

```
#fotos{
    margin-top:30px;
    width:650px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height:110px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
}
#fotos ul li{

    margin-right:4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#CCC;
    border:1px solid #555;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Meu HTML:

```
<div id="fotos">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Também queria poder clicar nos cantos e mostrar as próximas imagens.

Comment: Você poderia explicar mais sua pergunta? Pelo que entendi, você quer criar uma lista que não quebre, porém criando uma barra de rolagem na horizontal. É assim mesmo?

Answer (score 3):

Existe mais de uma maneira de resolver isso, e geralmente se faz por JavaScript. Mas tem uma maneira simples de resolver por CSS que eu gosto muito, e vou explicar aqui.

Como suas imagens (no caso os `<li>`) são *inline-blocks*, eles se comportam como texto em vários aspectos. Se você aplicar `white-space: nowrap` em um dos containers (`#fotos` ou a `<ul>`), você força que o texto não quebre linhas, conseguindo o resultado que você quer:

```
#fotos{
    margin-top:30px;
    width:650px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height:110px;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FmMry/

Se quiser criar uma funcionalidade para mostrar as proximas imagens aqui fica uma sugestão em baixo. (note que fiz um ajusta à altura da `#fotos` para `height:135px;`

Acrescente javascript/jQuery:

```
var scrollAtual = 0;
$('#tras, #frente').click(fazerScroll);

function fazerScroll(e) {
    var direcao = e.target.id == 'frente' ? 1 : -1;
    $('#fotos').animate({
        scrollLeft: scrollAtual += 200 * direcao
    }, 1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KLYyp/

Comment: Alternativamente ao uso do Javascript pra incluir botões de navegação, pode-se também ativar a barra de rolagem no `overflow-x` (http://jsfiddle.net/FmMry/4/). :)